# Content negotiation with REST for list of active and inactive products

Tags: rest, uri, naming-conventions

I've two pages, one displaying list of active products and the other inactive and are using same endpoint to display the products.

In the database the product table has a field `active = 1 or 0`, what's the standard REST style convention to differentiate between the two kinds of request.

`GET /products`   (list of active products)

`GET /products`   (list of inactive products)

Comment: FYI this is not "content negotiation" in the HTTP/REST sense. Normally, the term refers to getting the same data in a different format (e.g. JSON versus HTML or English versus French).

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can supply the 'active' flag as a parameter in your request.

```
 # this returns the list of active products
 GET /products?active=1

 # this returns the list of inactive products
 GET /products?active=0
```

Your server implementation can extract the value of the active parameter and respond accordingly.

Comment: good, it's like searching (query param), i was using headers earlier